# GIT command not found on Fedora 18

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, fedora

I am trying to deploy a Rails application using Capistrano. My application is on a Git repository on BitBucket.

Before deploying the application I needed to install Git on the server running Fedora 18. I tried the following:

```
sudo yum install git
```

and

```
sudo yum install git-core
```

Both commands showed that Git was installed successfully, but when I try to use the `git` command I receive a `git command not found` error.

How can I install Git with Fedora 18 and make this work?

**SOLVED**: Although, Fedora wrote that git has been installed, it was not. I tried to re-install git, following carefully what was written in the terminal during the installation and it worked.

Comment: Are you sure you are writing git with a small g, as in `git`, not as in `Git`?

Comment: I used `git` lowercase. I will edit my question.

Comment: What is the output of `echo $PATH`? Are you running as `root`, or a regular user? `root`'s `$PATH` is often different from regular users on Red Hat style Linuxes (and you shouldn't be running as `root` anyway).

Comment: `echo $PATH` prints: `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/root/.cabal/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/root/bin:/root/bin` . I am running as `root`.

Comment: Generally `git` would live in `/usr/bin`, which is in your path. I strongly urge you not to run as `root`, but if you are going to run as root you shouldn't need to `sudo` commands.

Comment: We can see where those RPMs put their binaries, though. Look in [`/var/cache/yum/`](http://superuser.com/questions/171302/where-are-the-rpm-files-after-installation-using-yum) for the RPMs that were installed and list their contents using `rpm -qpl <file>.rpm`. You should see a `git` executable in some `bin` directory. Once you have that, try running it with an explicit path, e.g. `/usr/bin/git`.